# How to keep a websites tasks alive after the website is closed

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing an application for the web, but, the problem is a task may take a long time to complete (minutes or hours). During this time I assume the website will time out or similar.

Let's assume the user can click the Start button and various processes are carried out. My question is about keeping the process (the task) alive, even if they leave the website, without configuring IIS (if possible).

Simply, if I spin off a new thread to perform a long winded background task, is that background task still owned by the application (the website) and if I close the application (the website) will it automatically be aborted or will it continue?

I guess the better way would be for the code behind to start up a process on the server (a different application) but, I'm more keen on understanding how the thread works.

Comment: Any worker process can exit at any time. Search for "ASP.NET background work". Very hard.

Comment: Check IRegisteredObject interface and how to set up long lived tasks wirh it

Answer (score 0):

To do that, start that Thread using Ajax. It would be sent asynchronously to the server and server can work on it until it completes the task.

Once you send the request to server browser doesn't need to be active. Server has to do the work and Browser is needed only to show the result of the request. Once the user would send the request, its not required for him to stay there. He can leave, and the server would continue the work.

User can navigate away from the Website and don't have to stay in the website for the process to complete. It would then depend on the System to complete the task.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as per the OP, it could be open for hours... It is not ideal to expect the user to keep the browser open, I'm interested if the thread dies when the application dies (Despite it being a new thread).

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions, Ajax is not dependant of the relation between Browser and Server, once the request has been sent, the user can close the browser and nagivate away.

Comment: oh... wow. I didn't realise that... My goodness, this could be the answer then, thank you

Comment: Ajax is client side , threads and processing are server-side. Client side would terminate once the request has been sent or the response has to be shown. Server side would be executed on the server. Without need of Browser.

Comment: This the confusion I have. Why use Ajax, why not use `Thread t = new Thread(() =>{ //do this });` .. .this way it is on the server side and as you say, no without need of browser (Sorry if I'm slow). If this is the case, then as soon as that new thread starts, then the browser can shut (ajax or thread)

Comment: No, I really think you first need to learn Ajax. Thread is a `C#` class executed on the Server. First learn the ajax please. :) Then you will understand why I said to use Ajax. :)